# Boot Gentoo Linux off SD Card on MacBook Pro

Tags: linux, usb, kernel, sd-card, gentoo

I'm trying to boot off an SD card on a MacBook Pro 5,4. I can get into GRUB and boot the kernel but I get a panic when it tries to find the root file system.

For some reason, no matter what option I choose to compile the kernel, it will not recognize the SD card, but the Gentoo minimal install CD has no problems whatsoever, that's how I installed it onto the SD card in the first place.

I'm using a EFI GRUB2 setup properly.

I followed [this guide](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/personal/cf-linux), and it didn't work. I chose Y, not M. So compiling *into* the kernel, not as a module.

Also, I can boot OpenBSD *off the same SD card* on the same laptop and it works great.

If anyone knows the options I need to enable or anyone who has done this before if you could help me it would be great.

LSUSB says the model is, `05ac:8403 Apple, Inc Internal Memory Card Reader`.

Comment: Make sure it is not a problem related to the UUID of the disk (grub trying to mount a root partition having a different UUID).

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that wants to know, the problem was linux was trying to mount root before all the USB devices were detected.

rootdelay=12 fixed this.